# The three defining properties of an equivalence relation can be formulated in algebraic terms

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

I am studying Naive Set Theory and stuck to understand algebraic part of equivalence relation. Can you please explain what these inclusions mean?

> The algebra of relations provides some amusing formulas. Suppose that,
> temporarily, we consider relations in one set $X$ only, and, in
> particular, let $I$ be the relation of equality in $X$ (which is the same
> as the identity mapping on X). The relation I acts as a multiplicative
> unit; this means that $IR = RI = R$ for every relation $R$ in $X$. Query: is
> there a connection among $I$, $RR^{–1}$, and $R^{–1}R$? **The three defining
> properties of an equivalence relation can be formulated in algebraic
> terms as follows: reflexivity means $I ⊂ R$, symmetry means $R ⊂ R^{–1}$, and
> transitivity means $RR ⊂ R$.**
>
> Halmos, Paul R.. Naive Set Theory (Dover Books on Mathematics) ([p.
> 41](https://books.google.com/books?id=lgdJDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA41)). Dover Publications. Kindle Edition.

Comment: In set theory, relations between elements of a set are encoded as sets of pairs, therefore the inclusions mean inclusions as sets.

Comment: Example: reflexivity. You have to check that if $I = \{ (a,a) \mid a \in X \} \subseteq R$ then relation $R$ is reflexive. And similarly for the other two properties of an [Equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition).

Comment: A *relation* $R$ on a set $X$ is a set of *pairs*: $R \subseteq X \times X$.

Comment: You can find several related posts here. For example: [If $R$ is a transitive relation, then $R\circ R\subseteq R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/876621) and [the questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/876621).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In set theory a binary relation on a set $X$ is some (any) subset of $X\times X.$ We can write $I_X=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$, which is a subset of $X\times X.$ For subsets $R, S$ of $X\times X$ we can write $$R^{-1}=\{(y,x): (x,y)\in R\}$$ and $$RS=\{(x,z):\exists y\,(\,(x,y)\in R\land (y,z)\in S\,)\}.$$ In particular $RR=\{(x,z):\exists y\,(\,(x,y)\in R\land (y,z)\in R\}$.

We can also show that a binary relation $R$ on $X$ is an equivalence relation  iff $I_X\subseteq R=R^{-1}=RR.$

BTW. In topology $I_X$ is called the diagonal of $X\times X.$

Comment: If you're interested in paring down the def'n, observe that if $\emptyset\ne R=R^{-1}=RR $ then $I_X\subset R.$